# How can I force eclipse to generate my setters with a return statement

Tags: java, eclipse, design-patterns, code-generation, builder-pattern

I want my eclipse to return `this` in a generated setter. This would be very useful for the [Builder-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

What eclipse does by default:

```
public void set{uppercase_field_name}({field_type} {field_name}) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

What i want eclipse to do:

```
public {class_type} set{uppercase_field_name}({field_type} {field_name}) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}
```

I found some templates that can be modified under:

`Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates`

But it is only possible to edit the body of the setter and not the setter signature.

Comment: Generally getters return values setters just sets.

Comment: i know that. but take a look at the Builder-Pattern

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer very quickly after i googled some more:

[Generate setters that return self in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294627/generate-setters-that-return-self-in-eclipse?rq=1)

I find this approach even better, because i don't have to apply the build pattern every time i generate setters. Which by convention should always be `void`.